# stringr - remove multiple spaces, but keep linebreaks (\n, \r)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am working on some raw text and want to replace all multiple spaces with one space. Normally,  would use stringr's `str_squish`, but unfortunately it also removes linebreaks (\n and \r) which I have to keep.

Any idea? Below my attempts. Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- "hello     \n\r how are you \n\r    all good?"
str_squish(x)
#> [1] "hello how are you all good?"
str_replace_all(x, "[:space:]+", " ")
#> [1] "hello how are you all good?"
str_replace_all(x, "\\s+", " ")
#> [1] "hello how are you all good?"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `stringr`, you may use `\h` shorthand character class to match any horizontal whitespaces.

```
library(stringr)
x <- "hello     \n\r how are you \n\r    all good?"
x <- str_replace_all(x, "\\h+", " ")
## [1] "hello \n\r how are you \n\r all good?"
```

In base R, you may use it, too, with a PCRE pattern:

```
gsub("\\h+", " ", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [online R demo](https://tio.run/##TYtBCsIwEEX3OcUwqwTrDRRXXkB0FyhpHZLC0CnTFtvTxxE3fZsPj/e1Vh46Tbr7edFhzBrcBpczYCFmgR9xjApFPpCUYJf1L4zEDFnkfUNn51Zp4tRTa9pvDWCM5YS2gMHlee38wTRgxUTK1@fjdQ@1fgE).

If you plan to still match any whitespace (including some Unicode line breaks) other than CR and LF symbols, you may plainly use `[^\S\r\n]` pattern:

```
str_replace_all(x, "[^\\S\r\n]+", " ")
gsub("[^\\S\r\n]+", " ", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just us a literal space in the regex instead of `\\s` or `[:space:]`:

```
str_replace_all(x, " +", " ") %>%
    cat()

hello 
 how are you 
 all good?
```

You can also include tabs by using `[ \t]`, `[:blank:]`, or `\\h` instead of  . In this case, you may want to use `{2,}` to select 2 or more of the same selector so you don't have to write the pattern twice (ie. `[:blank:][:blank:]+`):

```
y <- "hello     \n\r\t\thow are you \n\r    all   good?"

str_replace_all(y, "[:blank:]{2,}", " ") %>%
    cat()

hello 
 how are you 
 all good?
```

Comment: There is also `[[:blank:]]` that removes space and tabs. Since OP only wants to replace if there are two or more spaces, you could explicitly state that too `[[:blank:]]{2,}`, although you would obviously get the same result.